# Azure function v2, Core 3.1 Could not load file or assembly System.Memory, Version=4.2.0.0

Tags: azure, .net-core, serverless

I'm running locally an Azure function v2 on Core 3.1. Function connects reads events from an EventHub and write data to a Redis database.
While connecting function gets an error

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: 
 One or more errors occurred. (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.). 
 Pipelines.Sockets.Unofficial: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified. System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load the specified file.
```

Same Redis connection code works normally as expected outside the Azure function.

I have installed System.Memory nuget package v 4.5.3 into the project but it does not help.
There is no System.Memory version 4.2 listed in nuget for Core 3.1

function uses Startup

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(...))]
```

The project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Utf8Json" Version="1.3.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Configuration\Configuration.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was fixed by changing the Azure functions version to **v3** in project .csproj file.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem persists, verify that you are using the correct version of Azure Functions Core Tools (v3), it happened to me that I took version 2 from nodejs that is, I had version 2 installed in nodejs and version 3 in the folder From microsoft in the path they were both but I took the first one that was the nodejs one and it kept giving me the error until I delete the nodejs one, you can update it to version 3 in nodejs and I suppose it will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add true to your .csproj file:

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <UseNETCoreGenerator>true</UseNETCoreGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This does not help unfortunately. Have just added this line to all related project files,not just the function project. Still same error.

Comment: check this https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/160